# Wavelength on microstrip line

Tags: pcb-design, microstrip, wavelength

I am trying to calculate the wavelength on microstrip transmission lines. From what I have understand I should use the following relationship:

\$ l = c/(f*\sqrt(Er))\$ where Er is the dielectric constant of the material I use (Rogers 4350B), c is the constant value for the speed of light and f the frequency. Is that the correct formula? Does this change in case I use a differential coplanar waveguide?

Thank you

Comment: The geometry of the transmission line structure you use will change the effective value of the material permittivity. For stripline this will be just the permittivity of the material because the EM wave is contained completely within the material body, for microstrip it is more complicated because the EM wave is partially in the material body and partially in air.

Comment: Your board shop can validate your G coded controlled Impedances with a test fee using coupons. But a better design tool is Saturn PCB.exe